# Defining hash for vectors: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I am trying to define a hasher for vectors. I have a primary template for simple types, and a specialization for classes which have `operator()`.
However, I get an error `template parameters not deducible in partial specialization`. Could somebody please point out why?

```
 template <typename T> struct hash<vector<T>>
  {
    size_t operator()(const vector<T> &x) const
    {
        size_t res = 0;

        for(const auto &v:x) {
            boost::hash_combine(res,v);
        }

        return res;
    }
  };

  template <typename T> struct hash<vector<enable_if_t<true_t<decltype(sizeof(declval<T>()()))>::value, T>>>
  {
    size_t operator()(const vector<T> &x) const
    {
        size_t res = 0;

        for(const auto &v:x) {
            boost::hash_combine(res,v());
        }

        return res;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't really like partial specialization here, especially as it causes code duplication.

```
template <typename T> 
struct hash<vector<T>>
{
    template<class T>
    static auto call_if_possible(const T& t, int) -> decltype(t()) { return t(); }
    template<class T>
    static auto call_if_possible(const T& t, ...) -> decltype(t) { return t; }

    size_t operator()(const vector<T> &x) const
    {
        size_t res = 0;
        for(const auto &v:x) {
            boost::hash_combine(res,call_if_possible(v, 0));
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

(If this `hash` is actually `std::hash`, then the answer is "don't do it". You may not specialize a standard library template unless the specialization depends on a user-defined type.)

Comment: This is nice. The ellipsis saved the day again, +1.

Comment: @vsoftco Doesn't have to be ellipsis :) `long`, `void*`, `float`, `double`....the possibilities are endless.

Comment: Yes but `...` has the lowest priority, so why not using it. I've seen this technique many times and keep forgetting it (e.g. in checking in C++03 if a member function exists etc.).

Answer (score 1):

In your second template specialization `T` inside the `enable_if` is in a [non-deduced context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts), so the compiler cannot deduce it. It is effectively the same as:

```
template<typename T>
struct Identity
{
    using type = T;
}

template<typename T>
void f(typename Identity<T>::type x){} // T is non-deducible
```

Moreover, you have a "double" non-deducible context, because an expression containing `T` inside a `decltype` is non-deducible.

Comment: Can this be fixed without adding an extra parameter?

Comment: Yes, I think you can make a dummy default template parameter with the rhs containing the `enable_if`. I will edit.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to just dispatch internally.

Comment: @user2308211 I think I came up with a solution, probably there are other ways. See if it works for you, it can be adapted at once.

Comment: @T.C. You're right, I'm sure there are more clever solutions. I came up with this one mostly to brush up on my SFINAE ;) [`void_t`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am2is2QCvxY) SFINAE is also another option here, it looks like you can do *anything* with this simple beast.

Comment: Is it not possible to check whether `T` has `operator()`?

Comment: I don't think the OP can use this solution. He seems to be specializing `std::hash`, in which case adding the dummy parameter is not possible. Just have a single specialization for `std::vector<T>` and two `operator()` with complementary `enable_if` conditions.

Comment: @Praetorian Ohhh yes, darn. I just realized OP is specializing a `std` template.

Comment: @user2308211 Ignore my solution please. I didn't realized that you were specializing a template from `std`. Will remove the solution.

Comment: @Praetorian If this is about `std::hash`, the answer is "don't do it".

Comment: @T.C. Ah right, can only specialize `std::hash` for your own types, not other `std` types.

Comment: @vsoftco This approach still "works" (ignoring the UB) even in that case - just do the SFINAE in an auxiliary template, and then partially specialize the original to derive from the auxiliary one.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah I thought about it, but it's too clunky. I'd definitely use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

for what it's worth, here was my first attempt - handles ADL-lookup of hash_value as well as the one in the boost namespace:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
struct hash_value_defined
{
    template<class U> static auto boost_hash_value_test(U*p) -> decltype(boost::hash_value(*p),
                                                             void(),
                                                             std::true_type());

    template<class U> static auto adl_hash_value_test(U*p) -> decltype(hash_value(*p),
                                                             void(),
                                                             std::true_type());

    template<class U> static std::false_type boost_hash_value_test(...);
    template<class U> static std::false_type adl_hash_value_test(...);

    static constexpr bool boost_value = decltype(boost_hash_value_test<T>(nullptr))::value;
    static constexpr bool adl_value = decltype(adl_hash_value_test<T>(nullptr))::value;
    static constexpr bool value = boost_value or adl_value;
};

template<class T, class A, std::enable_if_t<hash_value_defined<T>::value> * = nullptr >
size_t hash_value(const std::vector<T, A>& v) {
    size_t seed = 0;
    for(const auto& e : v) {
        boost::hash_combine(seed, e);
    }
    return seed;
}



int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    vector<int> x { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    auto h = hash_value(x);
    cout << h << endl;
    return 0;
}
```